# Raphael drag and drop

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, raphael

I have a problem with :

```
path.drag(onmove, onstart, onend)
```

In particular, I have defined a function like this:

```
function onmove(x,y)
{
   console.log(x,y);

}
```

My problem is that x and y are not relative to my paper, how can I get the right coordinates?
I can't use JQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this demo, it should help you:

**http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/**

```
move = function (dx, dy) 
{
   // Move main element
   var att = this.type == "ellipse" ? {cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy} : 
                                               {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy};
   this.attr(att);

   // Move paired element
   att = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? {cx: this.pair.ox + dx, cy: this.pair.oy + dy} : 
                                               {x: this.pair.ox + dx, y: this.pair.oy + dy};
   this.pair.attr(att);   

   // more on the jsfiddle site
}
```

Comment: Great Demo! Thanks so much (even though you like A.S. Roma (I like Milan, I'm Italian)!

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates being returned are likely relative to the window. However you can calculate the offset of your paper from document.body by using a function such as that described at
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Then just compare the onmove coordinates to your paper coordinates.

If your page allows scrolling you will need to take that into account to.